# JQuery test value coming back from select

Tags: jquery

It has options with values `true` and `false`.

I have some jQuery here:

```
$("#myselect").change(function () {

            var accepted = $(this)[0].value;
            alert(accepted);

            if(accepted == false) {
                alert("Hi");
             }
        });
```

What I don't understand is why the Hi message is never shown.

The condition in the `if` is always coming through `false`.

Could someone please help me with this I'm fairly new to jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `value=""` of an `input` is a string:

```
if (accepted == 'false')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nAteT/

Answer (score 2):

The value of a select is a string, not a boolean.  A non-empty string is evaluated as the true value so it will never be equal to the boolean false.  You should do your comparison as a string.

```
$("#myselect").change(function () {

     var accepted = $(this).val();
     alert(accepted);

     if (accepted == 'false') {
         alert("Hi");
     }
});
```

Comment: @Gremo - just cut/paste his example, focusing on correcting the test not the rest.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Is there some case when a browser may return a `select` DOM value from `.value` that's not as accurate as `.val()`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I don't think that a select DOM element has a value property.  What it would have is a selectedIndex property and an options collection, that you could use to access the option and get its value.

Comment: It's possible in browsers there may be a difference (hence my question), but in FF 7.0.1, IE9, and Chrome latest... http://jsfiddle.net/8vNPW/

Comment: @JaredFarrish - ah, it is in HTML5 and should be in newer browsers. It is the value of the first selected option, so it would differ if it were a multiselect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the value of your dropdown is `'false'`, which is a string, whereas `false` is a boolean.

So change your check to `if(accepted == 'false')`.